# Rendering Problems Android

Tags: android

i'm new here , so i started developing for android like doing begginer apps like "Hello Word" , and it worked for first time...

The problem is , after updating Android Studio to 1.5 , when i open my project it gives me a error saying :

The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

This is my activity_main file :

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Comment: Welcome @stackoverflow. please describe more about your problem.

Comment: Welcome! Please read this [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This is the error :   The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

Comment: Probably you are missing a library with that classes, maybe the support library?